# How to inherit a db.ReferenceProperty on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore

I have something like this in my datastore:

```
class Referenced(db.Model):
    foo = db.StringProperty()

class Parent(db.Model):
    ref_key = db.ReferenceProperty(Referenced, collection_name='items')

class Child(Parent):
    foo = db.StringProperty()
```

So, now if I create a `Referenced` instance and a `Child` referencing that instance, like this:

```
def get_referenced():
    referenced = Referenced()
    referenced.put()
    item = Child(ref_key=referenced.key())
    item.put()
    return referenced
```

and try to access `referenced.items` I will get an empty list because appengine is quering the datastore for `Parent` instances with a `ref_key` equals `referenced.key()` and obviously there are no instances of `Parent` in the datastore so it returns an empty list.

So my question, is this a bug? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong. Is there a way I can achieve this behaviour?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not a bug. Other wise you would end up with a name clash for the back references as Child and Parent would have the same collection name items.

You would need to use PolyModel to do what you want.

If you are starting out, then you should stop right now and move over to ndb.  If you have an existing code base, then disregard this bit of advice.

Comment: So you are telling me that's not possible. The only possible solution would be to give `Child` a new db.ReferenceProperty field?

Comment: Pretty much.  I have a large project based on `db` and we had to define the reference properties in the child classes.  We wanted to name the collections, and they have to be different for every class that references the same class otherwise you get a duplicate collection name.  We couldn't find a way around it.  If you use `ndb` none of this is relevant of course.

Comment: Also the binding for the reference property is done at the base class definition.  You could look at using PolyModel's as the base class of Parent then it should work.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! Sadly I'm stuck with `db` but thanks!

Comment: If you chnage the base model of Parent to db.PolyModel then you can do what you want.  It also means you can get all Parent/Child  that reference Referenced in a single collection.  Using the inheritance model you currently have will mean you need two collection names and two separate queries to get all `Parent`s referencing `Referenced` and all `Child` referencing `Referenced`.